# Multiplicative identity of four element field

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

I have to use $Z_2 \times Z_2$ as my starting point of a four-element field. The addition Cayley table is simple enough if I just add components ($(0,0)$ is the additive identity), but I need help making the multiplication table. The layout of the table is forced (it is identical to the group $Z_3$ because it doesn't contain the additive identity), but how do I know which element is the multiplicative identity?

In fact, I can arrange any of the elements, so how can I figure out what the correct arrangement is? I could test distributivity, but I'm curious if there is a less tedious way than making 6 different multiplication tables and going through distributivity for them all.

Comment: Did you try a few possibilities? Once you pick the identity for multiplication everything else is given, so you can immediately check if it works.

Comment: $GL_2(\Bbb{F}_2)$ acts transitively on $\Bbb{F}_2\times \Bbb{F}_2-(0,0)$ so any element works as the identity.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft no, i didnt try them all (in fact, i just tested distributivity with (0,1) as the identity, and it worked). youre saying somehow distributivity works regardless of what nonzero i choose for the identity? that seems kinda of magical.

Answer (score 2):

The format $\Bbb Z_2\times \Bbb Z_2$ is helpful for the addition, but is *irrelevant* for a field's multiplication operation.

In lights of that, you can choose *any nonzero* to play the role of $1$, because denoting the nonzero elements by $a,b,c$ in any order, we always get $a+b=c$, so any permutation that fixes $(0,0)$ is an automorphism of the additive group.

Comment: thank you but could you please elaborate a bit more how that means i dont have to test distributivity on the different arrangements? i see how everything is an additive self inverse and adding any two distinct ones results in the third, but i cant quite connect that to how it helps me with distributivity.

Comment: You have to check distributivity. But once it's done, you can apply any permutation to obtain another field structure (with another identity).

Comment: sorry, but lets say i pick a multiplicative identity and test distributivity and it works. how do i know i dont have to test the other nonzero elements to see if they work or dont work?

Comment: If you have an additive isomorphism $f:A\to B$ and a ring [field] structure on $A$, the operation $b\cdot b':=f(f^{-1}(b)\cdot f^{-1}(b'))$ will satisfy the same properties and defines an isomorphic ring [field], namely $f$ itself will turn into a ring [field] isomorphism.